# Am I overusing Spring singletons?

Tags: java, spring

I have read many bad things about Singleton design pattern, but from what I gather, Spring singleton is not the same thing and it's perfectly fine to use it.

However recently I started wondering if I am not overusing that in the new application I am working on. Almost all of my classes in this application are Spring singleton beans. It's a Jersey web service with few service classes that would have business objects classes injected (IoC) that would contain all the business logic and communicate with DAO classes, which are also injected by Spring.

I thought that because I can make all my classes stateless easily, so there is no thread safety issues and because Spring has the instance of the class cached, performance-wise this would be reasonable solution.

I have since seen an application developed for my company by third party supplier, which is software house and they have all their Spring beans defined as "singleton=false", even though most of them dont hold any state. I started wondering, would that be a best practice approach to Spring beans and if I am in fact overusing singletons?

Would anyone have any comments on the matter in terms of best practices? Should I use Spring singleton whenever I can or should I stay away?

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as "overusing." Just make sure that you're using them appropriately (i.e. scope your beans properly). For more information, see [Bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

Comment: I think you're fine.  I'm not so sure about the third party supplier.  If they have no intention of ever creating multiple instances of a bean, then labeling it `singleton=false` is misleading to the reader of the config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine. The usual problem with singletons (aside from global mutable state, which it sounds like is not an issue here) is that the singleton manages its own single-ness (meaning things like static getInstance methods), making it difficult to test. In Spring that's handled by having the factory control the scope of the singletons.

Another troublesome aspect to singletons is how anything can get called from anywhere. You can handle this with a disciplined approach to layering.

Comment: The usual problem with singletons is that they get overused and the application data becomes fragmented and incoherent.

Comment: @Hot: agreed, if my edit doesn't cover that I'm open to suggestions.